# Add value coming from array in input field using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field that is added after an element, but the problem is It displays only one value on all input fields after page renders completely.

`<input type="text" class="form-control mkcInput" name="new_file_name[]" value="Logo 2" placeholder="File Name">`

**Jquery render input with same value after page load**

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="ajax-file-upload-container">
    <div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar" style="width: 400px;"><img class="ajax-file-upload-preview"
            style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: none;">
        <div class="ajax-file-upload-filename">2). 1572949612_ccf_education_logo.png (6.24 KB)</div>
        <div class="ajax-file-upload-progress" style="">
            <div class="ajax-file-upload-bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ajax-file-upload-red ajax-file-upload-1573123749310 ajax-file-upload-abort" style="display: none;">
            Abort</div>
        <div class="ajax-file-upload-red ajax-file-upload-1573123749310 ajax-file-upload-cancel" style="display: none;">
            Cancel</div>
        <div class="ajax-file-upload-green" style="display: none;">Done</div>
        <div class="ajax-file-upload-green" style="display: none;">Download</div>
        <div class="ajax-file-upload-red" style="">Delete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
        onLoad: function(obj) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "<?= SITE_URL ?>/lib/jQuery-File-Upload/load.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                subfolder: "classroom_course/<?php echo $company_id ?>",
                files_data: "<?php echo $cc_files; ?>"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    obj.createProgress(data[i]["name"], data[i]["path"], data[i]["size"]);
                }
                $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                    if ($('.ajax-file-upload-progress').children('.mkcInput').length == '') {
                        $('.ajax-file-upload-progress').children('.ajax-file-upload-bar').after('<input type="text" class="form-control mkcInput" name="new_file_name[]" value="' + val.file_name + '" placeholder="File Name">');
                    } else { }
                });
            }
        });
    },
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: can you post your html structure or working fiddle ?

Comment: @prasanth please check updated post

Comment: @RobinSingh - you have single container(.ajax-file-upload-container) or multiple?

Comment: @MohanRajput I have single, but inside that container everything is multiple

Comment: so you are saying as per the data dynamically divs(.ajax-file-upload-statusbar) are getting rendered?

Comment: @MohanRajput I need only input box to be render